# NextJS getStaticProps not updating on dev rebuild

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've been trying to get the page to render out data that I've updated in my CMS and for whatever reason, Next doesn't seem to be updated ServerSideProps or StaticProps when the dev server is restarted. It seems to be working and updating fine on the production server but when the dev server restarts, it should be running the build again, no?

Here's my current getServerSideProps code for context, though I feel the issue might lie elsewhere:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const resAll = await Axios.get(`https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories?token=${process.env.API_TOKEN}`);
    const stories = resAll.data

return {
    props: {
        stories
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Depending on your code, I don't think Axios is defined on the server-side of NextJS... Did you try the same code with fetch, instead of Axios.get?